# Что в Angular Означает тип Object[ ]?

Tags: typescript, angular

Что в Angular означает  `Object[]`  ?

буду рад посмотреть любую  информацию по этой теме.

Comment: нету типа `Object` или `Object[]` - почему нет?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: Тип `Object`  понял но что означает  `Object[ ]` , приведите  пример его использования, что он означает.

Comment: object[] это то же что и Array<object>. а по русски - массив объектов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object[]` в данном случаев используется один из вариантов [объявления типа "массив типа Object"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array)

Альтернативный способ: `Array<Object>`